# Colors detected are not equals to colors image

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to knowing which is the color of a pixel through it's x and y. The colors are from this image.

[image]

Capturing the colors with Photoshop I've got this list of colors:

```
"#5D385A", "#6D3B47", "#6F5C4B", "#50717A", "#547057", "#4C6180", "#717080", "#705574", "#726B59", "#5E4854", "#415A4B", "#425A64", "#3A4E6F"
```

However, when I try to get the color of a pixel from the image, this color doesn't match with the previous list. And, I've got 95 different colors when in the image there are only 13 different colors.

I open the image and get the color from a pixel with this class:

```
import PIL.Image
    
class Image:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.image = PIL.Image.open(file).convert("RGB")

    def get_color(self, x, y):
        color = self.image.getpixel((x,y))
        color = ("#%02x%02x%02x" % color).upper()
        return color
```

Here is a short list of x and y of positions where I take the color:

```
144, 74
140, 46
150, 53
85, 87
160, 48
147, 60
137, 49
149, 53
148, 60
143, 52
161, 30
166, 23
134, 38
146, 29
155, 40
129, 37
154, 66
153, 38
151, 33
128, 36
```

How is that possible? How can I get 95 different colors from the image when there is only 13 different colors?

**Edit I:**

I have get all the colors from each pixel in the image and no one has the color what I get with Photoshop.

I have got 256 different colors, this is the list and number times found it.

```
{'#885F7D': 15, '#541B47': 15, '#68355B': 819, '#65355D': 17, '#78384A': 19, '#7E3942': 19, '#7B3846': 4588, '#7C3346': 39, '#7D3046': 50, '#773F4C': 21, '#785A49': 4, '#775F49': 35, '#765C49': 17540, '#7A4648': 21, '#756349': 62, '#785B49': 56, '#7C3546': 14, '#765D49': 12, '#7A4F48': 14, '#7C3746': 29, '#785549': 7, '#775D4A': 8, '#785749': 8, '#551743': 1, '#6A3158': 39, '#68325A': 6, '#86617E': 1, '#66385D': 31, '#6C2C56': 6, '#6C2A56': 7, '#6D2B54': 3, '#678D97': 88, '#2C5B6A': 60, '#416C79': 43, '#3F717A': 7, '#43686A': 64, '#5C5F71': 32, '#465771': 3, '#5E5666': 14, '#5D4C66': 7, '#644160': 2, '#683C5F': 2, '#659197': 2, '#1C606C': 88, '#32767E': 61, '#227B84': 59, '#3A757A': 60, '#803342': 16, '#7D3745': 6, '#3A727B': 7374, '#3B7479': 3, '#36747C': 11, '#6C4450': 104, '#82303F': 18, '#852B3B': 28, '#694A56': 3, '#3D7179': 15, '#694E59': 15, '#7D3545': 11, '#387283': 30, '#3B717B': 17, '#3A727D': 16, '#7B5A48': 37, '#832B43': 11, '#3B7184': 21, '#2A7C66': 1, '#5D5D4E': 2, '#3B7180': 23, '#41715A': 6, '#45714D': 44, '#297D59': 6, '#407256': 32, '#417160': 13, '#437155': 5275, '#467055': 16, '#327A58': 7, '#68514E': 4, '#407756': 2, '#3C7356': 22, '#56654F': 17, '#437154': 15, '#387457': 30, '#3F7169': 14, '#4B6D54': 9, '#805C49': 105, '#735E4A': 10, '#7F5747': 63, '#755C49': 9, '#457154': 16, '#337558': 45, '#536B52': 18, '#735944': 95, '#7B614F': 96, '#5D6750': 36, '#437156': 43, '#69624D': 21, '#457151': 29, '#3D7172': 10, '#70604B': 10, '#487458': 2, '#45744D': 96, '#447352': 2, '#23596C': 2, '#3C6A7E': 59, '#3F696B': 41, '#64819B': 37, '#204D73': 92, '#3C5E82': 60, '#3A5E8A': 93, '#385B92': 1, '#3C6182': 4212, '#5D7F9A': 1, '#0C4A72': 2, '#305E82': 118, '#5C6982': 118, '#8F8D9B': 26, '#646473': 3, '#7B7482': 118, '#5A7169': 14, '#39714D': 12, '#727182': 2691, '#797189': 13, '#3E724D': 1, '#3B7155': 51, '#885947': 1, '#7D5744': 1, '#866251': 1, '#4F7056': 51, '#675C48': 106, '#707289': 10, '#736E6C': 11, '#746B51': 12, '#756C58': 116, '#82705C': 27, '#135941': 27, '#235D44': 105, '#255B44': 24, '#1D5943': 45, '#2B5C46': 108, '#2B5C45': 8, '#746C58': 5469, '#2E5C46': 17561, '#7E705B': 32, '#4F634D': 10, '#7B6E5A': 32, '#45614B': 14, '#707584': 117, '#6E788C': 1, '#72716E': 1, '#75677E': 117, '#746684': 1, '#766D59': 26, '#3D5F49': 11, '#255943': 33, '#957890': 39, '#7A5174': 117, '#7C4B7C': 2, '#775E6A': 62, '#727152': 39, '#726C58': 32, '#365E47': 12, '#683F63': 37, '#7A5476': 4212, '#79507A': 37, '#766166': 38, '#7A6D57': 15, '#6E6B56': 13, '#2D5D46': 5, '#696A54': 4, '#2C5B45': 8, '#626852': 8, '#305C46': 24, '#2E5C44': 26, '#7E577B': 2, '#7C567A': 55, '#7A517A': 58, '#784F79': 1, '#5F3855': 1, '#724F68': 57, '#727053': 59, '#856C77': 89, '#51303E': 91, '#62444F': 56, '#60404E': 1, '#767558': 56, '#654654': 7521, '#623F53': 16, '#674B54': 7, '#747057': 25, '#746B58': 40, '#623E53': 15, '#654754': 40, '#757158': 11, '#6F6C56': 2, '#644554': 29, '#613D53': 16, '#6B5555': 15, '#6F5E56': 15, '#756D57': 11, '#634354': 7, '#634153': 13, '#716457': 7, '#644254': 7, '#654354': 4, '#305C48': 3, '#726C59': 2, '#7E7055': 6, '#817155': 7, '#48615F': 4, '#0A5649': 1, '#2E5C3E': 26, '#135669': 2, '#2C5B68': 34, '#2B5C53': 21, '#2E5C41': 58, '#415F60': 3, '#0F5667': 5, '#2C5B64': 4676, '#2C5B66': 19, '#2C5B5B': 17, '#2E5C4D': 8, '#175966': 7, '#375D61': 2, '#61675B': 1, '#2F5B64': 20, '#2C5B60': 16, '#2F5B4A': 3, '#55675E': 2, '#2E5C4A': 8, '#275C64': 23, '#674654': 10, '#385260': 1, '#684553': 26, '#1C5E66': 46, '#564D59': 5, '#3D5660': 8, '#4F4F5B': 10, '#5E4A57': 7, '#365961': 5, '#47525D': 8, '#5C4B57': 4, '#614756': 2, '#5A4759': 36, '#504A60': 10, '#404B67': 7, '#2C5667': 18, '#8B6B75': 1, '#2B4D71': 876, '#2D5D62': 18, '#7C6D7B': 1, '#58728D': 16, '#0A365F': 16, '#21553E': 4, '#335F4B': 1, '#35624D': 20, '#3D6752': 4}
```

I don't understand anything. How is it possible that no one pixel has the color that I've got in Photoshop?

**Edit II:**

With the same code, I have got the color map of another image. This is the image:

[image]

The predominant colors that you can see in this image are these:

```
"#F50A22", "#00EC83", "#00A200", "#0007A4", "#9D132B", "#734500", "#6230FF", "#F42AFF", "#BEFF00", "#EC7800", "#65DCD1", "#FF6D00" : "#004500"
```

Executing the test, how I said, the same code. I've got that all these colors are found it in the image among others! And no one of them how in the first image.

The results are:

```
Colors matched: {'#F50A22': 2245, '#00EC83': 9437, '#00A200': 21039, '#0007A4': 8772, '#9D132B': 99, '#734500': 2970, '#6230FF': 112, '#F42AFF': 5271, '#BEFF00': 2380, '#EC7800': 3076, '#65DCD1': 6503, '#FF6D00': 4709, '#004500': 6612}
 colors matched: 13
```

And other colors found it in the image are:

```
Other colors: {'#FFFFFF': 1931, '#FCFFFD': 27, '#FAFFFB': 2, '#F7FEF9': 12, '#F4FEF7': 10, '#F6FEF8': 20, '#F6FDF8': 1, '#F9FEFA': 12, '#FBFEFC': 9, '#FEFFFE': 40, '#FAFEFB': 12, '#FBFFFC': 7, '#F3FEF6': 7, '#F4FDF6': 2, '#F5FDF7': 1, '#F2FDF5': 3, '#EEFDF2': 3, '#F2FDF6': 7, '#F4FEF8': 12, '#EFFDF4': 3, '#E5FCEC': 4, '#DAFAE5': 1, '#D3FAE0': 3, '#D4FAE0': 1, '#DAFAE4': 1, '#DFFBE8': 1, '#E9FCEF': 3, '#EDFDF2': 2, '#EFFDF3': 3, '#E2FBEA': 3, '#E2FCEA': 3, '#EFFEF3': 1, '#F2FEF5': 1, '#EDFCF1': 2, '#EBFDF0': 1, '#F1FDF4': 1, '#F3FEF7': 4, '#EDFDF1': 2, '#E7FCEE': 3, '#E3FCEB': 1, '#E0FCE9': 1, '#DCFBE6': 5, '#DAFBE5': 1, '#D9FAE4': 1, '#D9FAE3': 1, '#E3FCEC': 1, '#EEFDF3': 1, '#D7FAE2': 1, '#D1FADF': 1, '#D1FADE': 1, '#D6FAE2': 1, '#E1FBEA': 2, '#EBFDF1': 1, '#DFFBE9': 1, '#DEFBE7': 2, '#DBFBE5': 1, '#F6132A': 111, '#00EC84': 33, '#00EC85': 16, '#04EC86': 11, '#14EC87': 3, '#F40D23': 3, '#F20E24': 1, '#F50B22': 8, '#F11426': 2, '#F40C23': 1, '#EF1A28': 1, '#EE1B29': 1, '#F01827': 1, '#F21125': 1, '#F40D24': 1, '#F40E24': 1, '#774A03': 165, '#F40E23': 1, '#F50C22': 1, '#F6142A': 3, '#00EC82': 1, '#00EB82': 2, '#00EA7F': 1, '#00EB81': 1, '#6FE09C': 1, '#7E5416': 2, '#00A300': 78, '#00A500': 43, '#D9403B': 1, '#00AB16': 1, '#00A600': 40, '#00A700': 1123, '#5E2AFF': 2471, '#00B213': 2, '#00AA00': 6, '#7A4F0D': 3, '#6636FF': 2, '#00AE02': 2, '#00AC00': 3, '#00AB08': 2, '#00A800': 12, '#00A900': 8, '#00B317': 1, '#6C3CFF': 1, '#00AE00': 2, '#00AE14': 1, '#00A903': 1, '#7F55FE': 1, '#6CEE9F': 1, '#00AD00': 2, '#6CDCD2': 268, '#6A3CFE': 2, '#7549FF': 1, '#4ED688': 1, '#6B3DFF': 1, '#5E2BFF': 24, '#6839FD': 1, '#6231FE': 1, '#5E31FC': 2, '#00AF08': 1, '#00AC07': 1, '#6339FA': 1, '#5F33FB': 3, '#5F30FD': 3, '#00B10E': 1, '#656565': 1, '#00AB00': 2, '#00B02D': 2, '#6037F9': 1, '#5F2EFE': 2, '#5F3EF5': 1, '#5F32FC': 1, '#6040F4': 1, '#5F32FB': 2, '#6041F3': 1, '#6042F2': 1, '#7145FC': 1, '#5F2CFF': 10, '#6147EF': 1, '#6454EA': 1, '#6036F9': 1, '#685AEA': 1, '#00AF2F': 1, '#6B57EE': 1, '#00B110': 1, '#00AA02': 1, '#8ADBD3': 3, '#683CFB': 1, '#72DDD2': 3, '#6D47F8': 1, '#775EF3': 1, '#9CD7D1': 2, '#5E31FD': 1, '#00AB18': 1, '#82DCD3': 1, '#673EFB': 1, '#7450F9': 1, '#612EFF': 8, '#6236FB': 1, '#602CFF': 5, '#6B49F7': 1, '#602DFF': 7, '#5F2BFF': 6, '#6334FD': 1, '#2EEB8B': 1, '#704AFB': 1, '#6231FF': 1, '#6738FE': 1, '#612DFF': 3, '#3FEB8F': 1, '#66DBD1': 5, '#67D8D2': 1, '#00AE2B': 1, '#65DAD2': 1, '#F42DFF': 15, '#FC67FF': 6, '#F246FA': 1, '#F84CFF': 7, '#6233FF': 1, '#6ADCD2': 22, '#6132FE': 1, '#FBFEFE': 2, '#F434FF': 5, '#F8FDFC': 1, '#68DCD1': 33, '#6034FE': 1, '#FB5DFF': 2, '#FAFEFD': 2, '#F2FBFA': 1, '#6442FA': 1, '#6031FF': 1, '#F539FF': 7, '#F5FCFC': 1, '#E7F9F6': 1, '#F02AFF': 5, '#EFFBF9': 2, '#DDF6F3': 1, '#5F2EFF': 1, '#DD2BFF': 1, '#E82AFF': 1, '#F32AFF': 8, '#F744FF': 3, '#E7F9F7': 1, '#CFF2EF': 1, '#6136FD': 1, '#5F2AFF': 1, '#DD2AFF': 1, '#E42AFF': 1, '#EC2AFF': 2, '#E1F7F4': 1, '#C3EFEA': 1, '#6031FE': 1, '#EA2AFF': 2, '#ED2AFF': 1, '#DAF6F2': 1, '#BAEEE7': 1, '#6DDDD3': 2, '#6937FF': 1, '#ED37FE': 1, '#D7F5F1': 2, '#B6EDE6': 1, '#69DDD2': 2, '#74DFD4': 1, '#81DED9': 1, '#EF2BFF': 1, '#B3ECE7': 1, '#7ED7D4': 1, '#F22AFF': 2, '#D9F5F2': 1, '#B7EDE7': 1, '#DB39FC': 1, '#F12EFF': 1, '#E0F7F4': 1, '#C2EFEA': 1, '#87DBD3': 1, '#E737FE': 1, '#E6F8F6': 2, '#CCF2EE': 1, '#84DCD3': 1, '#ECFAF9': 1, '#D8F5F2': 1, '#65DCD0': 5, '#69DBCF': 6, '#6ADCD1': 1, '#98D3CD': 1, '#F440FC': 1, '#F42CFF': 7, '#F4FCFB': 1, '#6FD9CC': 2, '#6FD9CB': 3, '#6BDBCF': 1, '#7ED7C8': 1, '#80D3C1': 1, '#F531FF': 3, '#F42BFF': 35, '#FDFEFE': 2, '#F8FDFD': 1, '#83D8CB': 1, '#7ED3C2': 1, '#FF7100': 78, '#FEFFFF': 1, '#97D2CC': 1, '#FF7000': 40, '#FF6E00': 40, '#FF7925': 1, '#F33FF7': 1, '#6FDDD2': 2, '#FF6B00': 8, '#F62DF4': 1, '#F52BFB': 1, '#FF7409': 1, '#F62DF3': 1, '#F52BFC': 3, '#A2CFCA': 1, '#F73FE3': 1, '#F52DF9': 1, '#F42AFE': 1, '#FF7400': 4, '#FF730E': 1, '#FC36D5': 1, '#F62DF1': 1, '#F52BFD': 1, '#F52CFF': 6, '#F52DFF': 13, '#76DDD3': 2, '#FF6C00': 8, '#F831EA': 1, '#F52BFA': 3, '#F632FF': 1, '#8DDAD2': 1, '#F836E6': 1, '#F52BF9': 2, '#A4CCC8': 1, '#FF6A08': 1, '#7ADDD3': 1, '#FF690B': 1, '#F42BFE': 1, '#92D9D2': 2, '#FF6E0B': 1, '#F031FA': 1, '#A7C8C5': 1, '#FF6429': 1, '#FF7200': 62, '#FF671A': 1, '#7EDCD3': 1, '#EC35F6': 1, '#6CDACE': 1, '#6DDBD0': 1, '#FF671C': 1, '#FF7104': 1, '#FF6911': 1, '#FF642C': 1, '#FF6B23': 1, '#FF6E13': 1, '#FF7300': 5, '#F530FF': 1, '#F532FF': 3, '#6DDDD2': 1, '#F533FF': 1, '#F635FF': 1, '#F537FF': 8, '#F539FE': 2, '#F538FF': 9, '#00AC1A': 4, '#FF780E': 1, '#004B04': 29, '#FF873C': 1, '#FF7C1B': 1, '#FF7606': 4, '#FF780C': 1, '#FF7502': 1, '#FF7504': 1, '#FF770A': 2, '#004A03': 9, '#004A02': 5, '#F73FFF': 2, '#F435FF': 1, '#004700': 9, '#FF7A0F': 1, '#F52EFF': 1, '#F63BFF': 1, '#F638FF': 1, '#004600': 22, '#004B03': 3, '#004901': 8, '#FF7D1D': 1, '#F43EFB': 1, '#FF8533': 1, '#F62DF6': 1, '#FF7F24': 1, '#004902': 3, '#004900': 1, '#F441FC': 1, '#C1E057': 1, '#C2FD00': 5, '#C1F700': 1, '#C0FE00': 176, '#C4EE30': 2, '#C3E846': 1, '#C2FB00': 2, '#FEFEFE': 9, '#004C07': 11, '#B8FB00': 2, '#C3FB00': 1, '#FDFEFD': 5, '#BAFB00': 2, '#C5F11A': 2, '#B3F600': 2, '#BEFC00': 1, '#C1FD00': 7, '#FBFCFB': 3, '#BCDE52': 1, '#BBFE00': 9, '#FAFBFA': 2, '#B6F700': 1, '#BDFB00': 1, '#C3F800': 5, '#F331FF': 1, '#B2F500': 1, '#BDF900': 1, '#BDFD00': 1, '#BBFC00': 2, '#BDFE00': 10, '#C3EA40': 1, '#FCFDFC': 4, '#B5F600': 2, '#BCFD00': 7, '#C4E847': 1, '#CDFD09': 3, '#2337B3': 1, '#4251B6': 1, '#C5ED37': 1, '#D5FF3E': 17, '#0012A7': 625, '#004B06': 1, '#CFFE22': 5, '#B6F900': 2, '#C5FD00': 5, '#D3FF3C': 3, '#005010': 1, '#CBFD00': 5, '#C2FE00': 3, '#B8F900': 2, '#D2FE31': 8, '#C8FD00': 3, '#B9FA00': 2, '#C4FD00': 3, '#F8FBF9': 2, '#CCFE08': 3, '#F4F6F4': 2, '#C7FD00': 5, '#EBF1EC': 1, '#F8F9F7': 1, '#E1EAE4': 1, '#004701': 1, '#132AAF': 2, '#D5E2D8': 1, '#F1F5F2': 2, '#D1DFD5': 1, '#EC8417': 1, '#D4E1D7': 1, '#F3F5F3': 1, '#D9E4DC': 1, '#EB7800': 15, '#ED7B00': 133, '#F6F8F5': 1, '#DEE8E0': 1, '#E6EDE6': 1, '#FAFDFB': 1, '#EAF0EB': 1, '#EEF3EF': 1, '#EA7700': 2, '#F5F7F5': 1, '#C2E64E': 1, '#CAFD00': 2, '#F7FAF8': 1, '#E87700': 2, '#EA7800': 7, '#004C06': 2, '#CFFE20': 2, '#004A05': 1, '#E37600': 1, '#E67700': 1, '#00591D': 1, '#990A22': 2077, '#A6293C': 1, '#021EAA': 1, '#0007A3': 6, '#0009A1': 2, '#001697': 2, '#000B9F': 2, '#00119B': 1})
total other colors: 448
```

Both images are png.

How is it possible that I found all the colors among others in the second image and not found anyone of the color searched in the first image?

Answer (score 1):

you can see `13` colors yes! but the code doesn't because it's more precise than your eyes.

try zooming into the picture more, you'll see that between the colors there is another lighter one, which can consist of more than one color to go from one to the other, also I noticed some black and white at the left side "maybe it's just from your snipping tool or something"

but what I'm saying is, the code is right :)

[image]

you can try and create a photo using paint and only two colors with the `fill` tool, and make sure it's only one color without any gradient.

Comment: I'm agree with you but I've got around 3000 different positions and no one of them have one of the colors that should have to have and that is a little bit weird

Comment: try going through all the image's pixels an make a map of the colors, don't just try random coordinates

Comment: Hi @maha!!! I have made a map of the colors and no one of them is one of my list of colors. I don't understand anything :(

Comment: try this website to see the colors https://www.w3schools.com/Colors/colors_hexadecimal.asp , they're right I checked some, try an image with one color, black or white to make it easier for you to create, and check your code

Comment: also, check this website it might help https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/hex-codes-in-photoshop/td-p/9040860?page=1 , and try your code with rgb only, not hex

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and the solution. The problem is that I'm using images which has been created from a previous export. I mean, I have resized and make an export from an original imagin and in this momento something happens in Photoshop or whatever other program which produce an image with many other colors and not the original colors.

So, you have to run the process over the original version of the image, the export from the vectorized image. If you make an export from this export and then run the process, you will have problems like me.